# Is there an android phone that fits these criteria?

Tags: keyboard, verizon, htc

I'm not asking for recommendations, just if there is a phone that fits these criteria, and if so, what is it?

1. Android (preferably 2.2+)
2. Physical Keyboard
3. HTC
4. Verizon

Comment: Just curious: Why is HTC one of your criteria? I assume there are things that you tend to like about HTC phones--why not list those, instead?

Comment: @Matthew I'm leaning toward HTC mainly because of their reputation (and conversely, away from MOTO, Sony, etc) of releasing software updates. Many of the competitors' phones tend to get extremely delayed updates, if any at all (Cliq, for example). HTC Seems to have a pretty good track record of getting updates out the door quickly, even with their sense UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only HTC that I see on the Verizon site with an [Android search](http://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/store/controller?item=phoneFirst&action=viewPhoneOverviewByDevice&&deviceCategoryId=1#shop) is the Droid Incredible, which does not have a physical keyboard.

According the [HTC page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTC_phones#A_Series_.28Android_phones.29) only the Dream (A71XX), Espresso (MyTouch 3G Slide), and the Desire Z have physical keyboards. Those are all GSM phones, which won't work on Verizon's network (it being CDMA).

So the answer to your question is: **No such phone exists (at this time).**

Answer (score 3):

The EVO Shift 4G meets the first three criteria but fails the last. It's a Sprint-branded phone. Sprint uses CDMA, though, so an unlocked phone would work on Verizon's network. It runs on Android 2.2.

Edit: Sprint has now pushed out the Gingerbread (Android 2.3) update to the EVO Shift 4G